# Restrict Website to Xamarin Webview only

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

I have created a website in asp.net. Now i want this website to be used by
my xamarin(WebView) application only. So in other words i don't want anybody
acccessing this website outside my app. Is there a way to implement this restriction ?

I can only think of

```
if (Request.Browser.Type.Contains("WebView"))  
{

}
```

Comment: You could check the browser fingerprints and then create a list of devices based on their fingerprint. If the fingerprint does not match the client certificate you can reject it. However this requirement sounds like a complete headache in this sense and it could probably be spoofed. I would say that a proper implementation for this is not really reasonable to implement. Rather just add some type of basic auth or internal web service that your app uses to communicate against.

Comment: Add a custom header and try to take care of it.

Comment: @Rohit how is the custom header going to help me ?

Comment: You can generate some encrypted key and send via header, similar to auth token. Decrypt it at server and if the request if from the webview.

Comment: Thank you Rohit. I will try your suggestion.